# Selecting characters with non-banned account in PHP using MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I've got 2 tables:

accounts [id, name] and
characters [id, accountid, name]

Actually i'm selecting all characters with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM characters
```

How can i check from accounts, if accountid of that character is banned or not using the same query? I was trying using JOIN queries (which looks best way to go) but can't get them work. Here is what i tried:

```
SELECT * FROM characters WHERE accounts.banned = 0 INNER JOIN accounts
ON accounts.id = characters.accountid;
```

This shows no results. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is wrong. You are using `where` before `join`. Try this :

```
SELECT * FROM characters INNER JOIN accounts
ON accounts.id = characters.accountid WHERE accounts.banned = 0;
```

Refer this manual for join : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Answer (score 0):

`JOIN` should be before the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT * FROM characters 
INNER JOIN accounts ON accounts.id = characters.accountid 
WHERE accounts.banned = 0;
```

[JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
SELECT c.* FROM characters c,accounts a WHERE a.banned = 0 and a.id = c.accountid
```

Comment: @Alessandro: use suggested inner query